# Why was Agatha desperate to send the message?

Tags: the-thousand-worlds, nightflyers

In the first minutes of the first episode of the *Nightflyers* TV series, we can see a woman desperate to send a message to Earth. The desperation is real - she is risking her life, as she is being chased by an ax-crazy murderer. Her message:

> This is Dr. Agatha Matheson of the "Nightflyer".
>   We have sustained fatalities, structural damages. We... This is a warning.  Not a distress call.
>   Do not board this ship.
>   Do not bring the "Nightflyer" back to Earth.

After sending this message, she commits suicide. The TV show then runs a giant retrospection to show all that has happened over the months before these dramatic events have taken place.

In the penultimate episode (which takes us back to the scene from episode 1), we know that:

> There is an evil AI aboard this ship. But to Agatha's knowledge, this has been solved by imprisoning the AI behind firewalls. We know that the ship had an outbreak of some deadly mould that literally melted humans - again, this is solved. We know that close proximity to Volcrons increases psychic abilities - but that again is not a problem, since psychics are extremely rare.

So besides the single psychotic crew member (that is actually on Agatha's mercy), there is no real danger to anyone who would be wanting to take "Nightflyer" back. Of course, there is the whole unknown effect of the aliens on anyone in proximity, but she doesn't mention it at all.

Is this just a plot hole, put there to hook up viewers wanting to know about the "Great Danger" on board the ship or am I missing something?